# Line graph not working in d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I made a bar chart in d3.js that was working but now I want to have line chart but having some problem as line chart not getting rendered. Below is my code what I have tried please tell me where is wrong. Below is my HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">

    <title>D3</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle1.css" /> -->

    <style>
        body {
            color: #000;
        }

        .axis {
            font: 10px sans-serif;
        }

        .axis path,
        .axis line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #000;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }

        .bar {
            fill: steelblue;
        }

        .bar:hover {
            fill: brown;
        }

        #upleft {
            width: 320px;
            height: 600px;
            background: red;
            float: left;
        }

        #upright {
            width: 800px;
            height: 50px;
            background: green;
            float: left
        }

        #below {
            height: 600px;
            width: 1120px;
            background: blue
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="123.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<body>




    <div id="upleft">
        <label> List of Tables : </label><br>
        <div>
            <select id="dropdown1"></select>
        </div>
        <style>
            #listbox {
                display: none;
            }

            #listbox {
                position: relative;
            }
        </style>


        <div style="margin-left: 150px; margin-top: -30px; height: auto;">

            <select id="listbox" , multiple></select>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="upright">
        <div align="left">
            From : <input type="date" name="field1" id="field1" /> To : <input type="date" name="field2" id="field2" />
            <input type="button" onclick="render(true)" value="Submit" />
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="below">

        <div id="chart"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var jsonURL = 'avb.json';

        var myData = [];
        var fliterdata = [];
        var tempdata = [];
        var selectop = "";
        var selectDate = false;

        function filterJSON(json, key, value) {
            var result = [];
            for (var foo in json) {

                if (json[foo][key] == value) {
                    result.push(json[foo]);


                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        function selectValue(d) {
            // console.log("before op",selectop );
            switch (selectop) { //d object select particular value for Y axis 
                case "01":
                    return d.val001;
                    break;
                case "02":
                    return d.val002;
                    break;
                case "03":
                    return d.val003;
                    break;
                case "04":
                    return d.val004;
                    break;
                case "05":
                    return d.val005;
                    break;
                default:
                    //console.log("default");
                    return d.val001;
            }


        }

        var margin = {
            top: 20,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 80,
            left: 40
        };
        var width = 700 - margin.left - margin.right;
        var height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;



        var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangePoints([0, width], 1);

        var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height, 0]);

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x)
            .orient("bottom");

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left");

        var line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function(d) {
                return x(d.alphabet);
            })
            .y(function(d) {
                return y(d.frequency);
            });

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
        xScale.domain(tempData.map(function(d) {
            return d.date;
        }).sort(function(a, b) {
            return a > b;
        }));

        yScale.domain([0, d3.max(tempData, function(d) {
            return +selectValue(d);
        })]);
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis)
            .append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", ".71em")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("Y - Axis");

        svg.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", line);
        //});
        }
        var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);
        var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
        var hAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient('bottom').tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d"));
        var vAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient('left');
        var tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')
            .style('position', 'absolute')
            .style('background', '#f4f4f4')
            .style('padding', '5 15px')
            .style('border', '1px #333 solid')
            .style('border-radius', '5px')
            .style('opacity', 'o');



        function render(filterByDates) {


            d3.select('svg').remove();

            if (filterByDates) {
                selectDate = true;
                tempData = fliterdata;
                console.log("before date fliter data", tempData);
                var date1 = new Date(document.getElementById('field1').value);
                var date2 = new Date(document.getElementById('field2').value);

                tempData = tempData.filter(function(d) {
                    console.log(date1, date2);
                    //  alert(date1);
                    return d.date >= date1 && d.date <= date2;


                });
                console.log("After date fliter data", tempData);
            }

            .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
                .attr("y", function(d) {


                    return yScale(selectValue(d));
                })
                .attr("height", function(d) {

                    console.log("as", d.value);
                    return height - yScale(selectValue(d));
                })

        }




        d3.json(jsonURL, function(data) {

            myData = data; //data from json in mydata
            myData.forEach(function(d) {

                d.date = new Date(d.date);
                //d.value="";

                //d.name = +d.name;
                console.log(d.date, "Gt date");
                d.date = new Date(d.date + " UTC");
                console.log(d.date, "localtimezone date");
            });

            $("#listbox").on("click", function() {

                var key = $(this).val();
                console.log("key:", key);
                var value = $('#listbox option:selected').text();
                console.log("vaue:", value);

                selectop = String(key);

                selectop = selectop.slice(-2);
                console.log("mydata: ", myData);
                console.log("selectops:", selectop);

                fliterdata = filterJSON(myData, key, value); //selected value from user and picks the whole element that contains that attribute

                console.log("fliterdata: ", fliterdata);
                tempData = fliterdata; //graph made by temp data
                if (selectDate)
                    render(true);
            });
        });
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

My json file

```
[ {
 "name": "ABC",
 "date": 1459461600000, 
"attr001": "intSIGN1",
 "val001": "60", 
"attr002": "SIGN2",
 "val002": "5",
 "attr003": "SIGN3", 
"val003": "100.00", 
"attr004": "SIGN4", 
"val004": "0",
"attr005": "SIGN5", 
"val005": "Traesnotfound" 
}, 
{
"name": "ABC",
 "date": 1461176704000,
 "attr001": "SIGN1",
 "val001": "200", 
"attr002": "SIGN2", 
"val002": "70", 
"attr003": "SIGN3", 
"val003": "100.00",
 "attr004": "SIGN4",
 "val004": "670",
 "attr005": "SIGN5", 
"val005": "Traceinvalid"
 }, 

{ "name": "ABC",
 "date": 1459125900000,
 "attr001": "SIGN1",
 "val001": "500", 
"attr002": "SIGN2", 
"val002": "70", 
"attr003": "SIGN3", 
"val003": "100.00",
 "attr004": "SIGN4",
 "val004": "670",
 "attr005": "SIGN5", 
"val005": "Traceinvalid"
 },




 { "name": "XYZ", 
"date": 1459125900000, 
"attr001": "VISSE1",
 "val001": "100", 
"attr002": "VISSE2",
 "val002": "7",
 "attr003": "VISSE3",
 "val003": "300.00",
 "attr004": "VISSE4",
 "val004": "160",
 "attr005": "SIGN5", 
"val005": "not found"
 },

 { "name": "XYZ",
 "date": 1459461600000,
 "attr001": "VISSE1", 
"val001": "50", 
"attr002": "VISSE2",
 "val002": "70",
 "attr003": "VISSE3",
 "val003": "300.00",
 "attr004": "VISSE4",
 "val004": "230",
  "attr005": "SIGN5", 
"val005": "found"
 },

{ "name": "XYZ", 
"date": 1459461900000, 
"attr001": "VISSE1",
"val001": "300", 
"attr002": "VISSE2",
 "val002": "10", 
"attr003": "VISSE3", 
"val003": "500.00",
 "attr004": "VISSE4",
 "val004": "350",
 "attr005": "SIGN5", 
"val005": "not found" },

{ "name": "ABC", 
"date": 1462188244000, 
"attr001": "SIGN1",
"val001": "300", 
"attr002": "VISSE2",
 "val002": "10", 
"attr003": "VISSE3", 
"val003": "500.00",
 "attr004": "VISSE4",
 "val004": "350",
 "attr005": "SIGN5", 
"val005": "not found" } ]
```

Comment: Please include a snippet of your JSON file.  When you ask questions people need to be able to fully reproduce your code in order to provide answers.

Comment: @Mark have added json file

Comment: @priyanka Your code has multiple syntax errors but mainly conceptual errors. Did you copy it from somewhere?